# Firebug constructor function vs user function

Tags: javascript, dom, function, firebug

I made a quick search about what is the meaning of Firebug DOM tab coloring and I see the the explanation below [from here](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DOM_Panel)

> Red colored bold text points "constructor function"
>
> Green colored bold text points "user function".

What is the difference between the two type of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jQuery` function *is* a constructor function (`$` is merely a reference to `jQuery`). You can see that when you see its definition:

```
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
},
…
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    init: function( …
```

You can reproduce this behaviour (the bold red coloring) when defining a constructor function *and* adding something to its prototype object, like

```
var testFunc = function () {
    /* nothing so far */
};

testFunc.prototype.baz = function () {
    /* nothing, this gets boring */
};
```

or even just a random number

```
testFunc.prototype.baz = 4;
```

Note that this doesn't comply with the actual definition of a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_Constructor_Function) in JavaScript. If you test the linked source code in Firebug, `car` will be colored green, not red. Furthermore, see [The Benefits of JavaScript Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462464/the-benefits-of-javascript-prototype).

Answer (score 1):

As Marcel's example shows, Firebug marks objects that typeof "function" and which have a property 'prototype' with at least one subproperty as a 'userClass'

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.7/content/firebug/dom.js#431

There really isn't any such thing as a "constructor function" in Javascript, just functions that can be used as constructors. Any function can be used to create objects, but it's only really interesting if the function has a prototype.