# Javascript classes vs objects, pros and cons?

Tags: javascript, performance, class, memory

In my most recent javascript program (which is mostly for fun and proof-of-concept than anything else) I have a lot of different kinds of objects and of each kind I'd have a fair amount of "instances". So I was thinking I should use classes for these, however since they are very simple I could simply construct them directly instead of using classes...

Example of what I mean:

```
//I'm making a "car" object that has the properties model, miles, value and color
//using a class like:
function car (model, miles, value, color) { .... }
//so I'd create a new car by using:
mycar = new car(model, miles, value, color);

//However for an object so simple I could also do:
mycar = {model: model, miles: miles, value: value, color: color};
```

I'm guessing the latter method would be more efficient in some way (no call to the class's function), but is it worth it?

To decide that I'd like to know about pros and cons of using classes vs using regular objects. Like do classes take up significantly more memory for example?

Comment: use constructors when you need to inherit prototypes. use literals when you just need a collection of values for a task.

Comment: It's down to OOP vs procedural programming.

Comment: I would recommend always favoring readability and maintainability over performance.  If it cleans up your code to have a class, go for it.  You have the extra function in memory to define it, and the extra function call to invoke it.  Unless the circumstance is extreme, the costs are negligible.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answers so quickly :)
I'll have to see if I could make good use of prototypes in this case and whether using classes will make it more readable, because it might just be the opposite for some small objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [prototype based vs. class based inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816071/prototype-based-vs-class-based-inheritance)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In terms of performance, the difference comes when you add methods. If you use object literals each object needs to have a field for each method:

```
obj1--> { x: 10,
          f1: method1,
          f2: method2 }

obj2--> { x: 17,
          f1: method1,
          f2: method2 }
```

With classes, you can share common properties behind a shared prototype:

```
obj1--> { x:10,
          __proto__: --------> { f1: method1,
         }              /---->   f2: method2 }
                        |
obj2--> { x:17,         |
          __proto__: ---/
        }
```

That said, the performance differences are only going to matter if you instantiate a *lot* of objects and those objects have many methods and many of those methods are closures. If I were you I would give a greater emphasis to code style issues: for example, with the object literal method you can use closures to simulate private variables while if the methods are in a shared public prototype then all your instance variables need to be public.

Comment: private variables can be added in constructor too.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll be using the literal method for most of my objects except for a few larger ones that need to have functions of their own.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, [JavaScript is not class-based](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418980/1048572), what you have is just a special function. So what's the difference?

- An object instantiated by a constructor has an prototype object from which it inherits properties. This prototype object is shared by all object constructed by the same function. You can put common methods on there, which will be [considerably faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180790/defining-methods-via-prototype-vs-using-this-in-the-constructor-really-a-perfo).
- The constructor function is called. You can use it to initialise your object (fill in defaults, validate parameters, etc) and you have a scope to construct closures.

Even if for some objects you don't need prototypes, a function returning plain objects for you has still advantages. At least, it provides you the flexibility to change the implementation without the need to change every instantiation in your codebase. Therefore, start with a simple

```
function Car (model, miles, value, color) {
    return {model: model, miles: miles, value: value, color: color};
}
```

(which you can even call with `new` without effects) and extend it later if you need to.

Comment: Javascript classes we're introduced as of ES2015

Comment: @DylanLarsen True, but the OP wasn't using the `class` syntax. I updated the phrasing nonetheless.