# Does using strongly typed classes result in more efficient Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on porting a large .NET WinForms business application to Angular. I have a data model with a large number (~1500) of entities. In the .NET application each entity is modelled by a simple class, the vast majority of these classes have no methods beyond the properties exposing the fields of the entity. They are essentially used only for type safety.

Is it a good idea to reproduce this in a Javascript based application or (since I am using Typescript) should I just use interfaces to enforce compile time type safety? Given Javascript's more flexible approach to defining objects I could just add the properties i need at run time?

I am particularly interested in knowing whether the sheer bulk of the class definitions would be a performance hit, or rather if having the strongly typed classes would actually increase performance.

Comment: What leads you to suspect that they would improve performance?

Comment: In compiled languages knowing the shape of the data means the code can be optimised, I'm just not sure if this same idea applies to Javascript?

Comment: No, it's really just a compiler trick - similar to the get; set; in .Net

Comment: Types affect only type checking during compilation. They don't exist at run time (with the exception of types emitted by decorators). *Given Javascript's more flexible approach to defining objects I could just add the properties i need at run time?* - and you lose type safety this way. If you don't need things that are provided by TS, i.e. type safety, IDE autocompletion and self-documentation, stick to JS.

Comment: I thought the TS property typings were somehow preserved in the JS if you used getters and setters but it seems my intuition is once again found lacking when it comes to JS! Basically a function doesn't have reliable return type - it could return anything? However I don't see how i lose type safety by adding properties to objects at runtime?  Suppose i have some JSON returned from an API call, use JSON.parse and set the resulting object to a variable of type defined in my interface. From this point on I have compliler type checking and IDE autocompletion which is exactly what I want, no?

Comment: Yes, that's what's usually done with parsed JSON, and although you convinced TS compiler that the object really has these properties with type assertions, you cannot be sure that it's true. If this needs to be improved, class instance can be created from plain JSON, and class constructor is responsible for checking if the props are there, otherwise it throws an error at run time. You need to address users with @ if there's more than one in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tldr; I would just use interfaces to define the shape of data you need, since that is easier to use in JS code.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19185306/2378943) points out that it is not a big difference until you instantiate a lot of object - I would say millions of objects per second.

[Here's a good article](https://medium.com/engineering-livestream/javascript-classes-v-closures-2-3-9fa3b1296b16) on performance in Node, which will give you an idea of how it will be in Chrome (saying nothing about other browsers).

A bigger problem than performance efficiency, is developer efficiency. And I would argue that interfaces, as a more light-weight language construct, are easier to reason about than classes. In fact, it's easy to mixin an existing interface with another type, interface, or anonymous type like this:

```
interface Map {
  map: Function
}

interface Reduce {
  reduce: Function
}

type CustomType = Map & Reduce & { sum: Function }

const a: CustomType = {} // now you need to implement map, reduce, and sum
```

You just get so much reasoning power, without the class keyword, and 0 overhead. However, if classes meshes better with your team/codebase/use-case, go for it. You won't incur significant runtime overhead with just 1500 of them.