# OOP JavaScript: Usage of "this" necessary within methods?

Tags: javascript, oop

Shall one use the "this" keyword when accessing object-properties from **within** the object which has the property.

I've made this demo. Both way worked fine.

So, is there a good reason to add the "this" or can one leave it out?

```
function CalcCircle(radius) {
  this.radius = radius;

  this.getCircle = function () { 
    // Accessing the property "radius" WITH "this".
    return (Math.PI * this.radius * 2); 
  };
}

// Without the "this" keyword.
function CalcCircle2(radius) {
  this.radius = radius;

  this.getCircle = function () { 
    // Accessing the property "radius" WITHOUT "this".
    return (Math.PI * radius * 2); 
  };
}

var o1 = new CalcCircle(10);
var o2 = new CalcCircle2(10);

console.log('With "this": ' + o1.getCircle());
// With "this": 62.83185307179586
console.log('Without "this": ' + o2.getCircle());
// Without "this": 62.83185307179586
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you use `this` in your example of `CalcCircle2` only differetiates which variable you actually use. With `this` you use the property. Without `this` you are using the argument of the constructor function (through JS closure).

Generally speaking it's better to use the argument once and then rely on your field that you created.

You may also want to check out attaching methods through prototype instead of creating them in constructor, in which case you'll be forced to use the field:

```
function CalcCircle2(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}

CalcCircle2.prototype.getCircle = function () { 
    // Accessing the property "radius" WITHOUT "this".
    return (Math.PI * this.radius * 2); 
};
var o2 = new CalcCircle2(10);
o2.getCircle();
```

Comment: Is there an advantage in defining the methods upon prototype-object instead of attaching them to "this"?

Comment: @bo256 Here's a better link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816071/prototype-based-vs-class-based-inheritance

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that when you just refer to `radius`, you are referring to the value that was passed in when the object was created.

If the value of `radius` changes on the circle during run time, the value you get back from `getCircle` is not going to be updated in the second one.

Comment: You're perfectly right. If you change the name of the property to let's say 'this.rad' and then try to access to access 'rad' without 'this' => Error because undefined. Understand it now. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you can get away with not using the `this` keyword in the second implementation is because your function `getCircle` is accessing the `radius`from the parameter passed in from `CalcCircle2`.

```
// Without the "this" keyword.
function CalcCircle2(radius) {

  this.getCircle = function () { 
    return (Math.PI * radius * 2);
    //                ^^^^^^
    // radius is searched for in this function scope...
    // was not found.
    // checks next scope chain...
    // radius is found!
  };

}
```

The purpose of the `this` keyword is to bind certain variable to an instance of an object.

In this particular implementation, you don't *need* to use the `this` keyword, however it's good practice to start using it in OOP when defining properties of an object.

**Side Note:**

The `this` keyword becomes much more useful when creating objects using [prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). This is when you create objects and give them properties that can be inherited from any instance of that object.

```
var CalcCircle = function(radius){
  this.radius = radius;
}

CalcCircle.prototype.getCircle = function(){
  return (Math.PI * this.radius * 2); 
  //                ^^^^
  // Now we need this
};
```

In this example, we need to use `this` to reference the variable associated with the object within other functions we are defining.

Comment: your explanation is vague, you can correct it with example from @thgaskell

Answer (score 0):

Both radios is different

In function one where you are using this.radius

```
function CalcCircle(radius) {
  this.radius = radius;

  this.getCircle = function () { 
    // Accessing the property "radius" WITH "this".
    return (Math.PI * this.radius * 2); 
  };
}
```

You are accessing the property of Object.

whereas in Second function

```
function CalcCircle2(radius) {
  this.radius = radius;

  this.getCircle = function () { 
    // Accessing the property "radius" WITHOUT "this".
    return (Math.PI * radius * 2); 
  };
}
```

when you are you are using parameter of CalcCircle2 function.