# Create a JavaScript Class from a JSON Object

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON file which contains information data, and I get this data using AJAX using this function to fetch it.

```
function fetchJSONFile(callback) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                if (callback) callback(data);
            }
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', 'database.json');
    httpRequest.send(); 
}
```

And I fetch it to assign it to the object of the current Class:

```
fetchJSONFile(function(data){ 
    employes = Object.assign(new Employes(), ...data.Employes);
    console.log(employes);
})
```

The data within my JSON file is this:

```
{

"Employes":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "fullName": "Test Test"
        }
    ],
"Infos":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "address": "Test Test test test test",
            "employes": 1
        }
  ]
}
```

My question is how to generate Classes automatically of each object type from the JSON file.

Using my code like for example I want to generate `Employes` and `Infos` Classes automatically here without having to create them manually.

```
fetchJSONFile(function(data){ 
        employes = Object.assign(new Employes(), ...data.Employes); //Generate Classes automatically here from data type
        console.log(employes);
    })
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Make `Employee` class accept an object from your response as a constructor argument, then build the object. Something like `let employee = new Employee(data.employees[0])`

Comment: @IsaacVidrine I assume `Employes` was chosen arbitrarily and can stand in for any string? Maybe OP can confirm.

Comment: Do you want them to just have the same properties as `employee` object or to actually **be** an employee object?

Comment: In standard OOP language (not in javascript terminology), are you trying to generate a new class based on the JSON data (probably because you don't  know what the classes will be called), or are you just trying to instantiate objects of various pre-defined classes on the fly? Either is relatively easy in Javascript -- which, by the way, does NOT have classes (except as syntactic sugar), -- but the algorithms are going to be pretty different.

Comment: @Cat I want to generate new classes based on the JSON data, for example in my code I have Employes and infos on json, so I want to create Employes and infos classes automatically on my js code

Comment: There is no point in doing this. A class is really just a convenient way to create objects. You already have the objects, so no need for a class.

Answer (score 1):

JS does not natively have classes in the same sense as most OOP languages. You probably come from an OOP background, you should learn about JS's [prototype based inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816071/prototype-based-vs-class-based-inheritance).

You will understand that **you don't actually have to create those classes**. You can achieve what (I think) you are looking for via simply writing:

```
fetchJSONFile(function(data){ 
        employes = data.Employes; 
        // or, if you wish to make a copy
        //employes = data.Employes.map(e => {...e})
        console.log(employes);
    })
```

Comment: The `Employes` and `Infos` classes may have methods defined.

Comment: As the OP said they would like to generate those classes automatically, I assume that there are none. I might have misunderstood the question though

Comment: Mmh I see. I thought given that they are calling the `Employes` constructor it already exists and they just don’t want to reference it explicitly. But after re-reading the question I think you are right. We should get clarification from the OP either way.