# Objects by class-like pattern

Tags: ecmascript-6

Exists follow text in ECMAScript specification, sounds like:

> Although ECMAScript objects are not inherently class-based, it is often convenient to define class-like abstractions based upon a common pattern of constructor functions, prototype objects, and methods. The ECMAScript built-in objects themselves follow such a class-like pattern. Beginning with ECMAScript 2015, the ECMAScript language includes syntactic class definitions that permit programmers to concisely define objects that conform to the same class-like abstraction pattern used by the built-in objects.

From all of these I interested in:

> The ECMAScript built-in objects themselves follow such a class-like pattern

What does it mean?

---

I think the `class-like pattern` means that the programming style is similar to the programming style using classes.

For example:

Accessing the property: `obj.property;` or calling the method: `obj.method();`

If it is not it, explain why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816071/prototype-based-vs-class-based-inheritance

Comment: Consider an array. Though you can create it using special syntax `const arr = [1, 2, 3]` it is still constructed using `Array` constructor. Which has a prototype with a bunch of array methods `map, filter, etc`. This is pretty much true for every built-in objects `RegExp, Map, Set, Function, Object, Promise, etc` So you could say that built-in objects follow the pattern.

Comment: Do you know what the "class-like pattern" is or does that need explaining as well?

Comment: @Bergi I have suggestions, but it will not be superfluous, and explain it

Comment: @MaximPro OK I'll wait for your edit

Comment: @Bergi a little, but added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the "class-like pattern" means that the programming style is similar to the programming style using classes.

Yes, exactly. See [class-based programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming) on Wikipedia.

> Accessing a property or calling a method

No, that's basic [object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(object-oriented_programming))-orientation. It doesn't need prototypes or classes for that.

What makes a [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)) is the instantiation of alike objects (with the `new` operator), the initialisation of instance data members (in the `constructor`), and the shared implementation of methods (in the `class` body).

Additionally, most class systems also feature inheritance with a superclass hierarchy. JavaScript achieves that (and the sharing of methods) via prototype inheritance.

You should be able to easily see how all the ECMAScript built-in objects follow this pattern.

Comment: Hmm. Regarding property access and method invocation. Why this does not apply to the `class-like pattern`. Can you give an example when accessing a property and calling a method does not relate to this style?
What makes the class clear.
When you said about the superclass, I correctly understand that inheritance goes like this: `class base {};` `class bar extends base {};` - in this example, base is a superclass, right? If this is the case then, as applied to ECMAScript, the Object class (more precisely, the `constructor`) is a superclass for functions, arrays, numbers, strings, and so on.

Comment: I once again looked at the specification and found such a sentence in the definition of the Object constructor (it occurs a lot where it is, almost in all built-in objects): `is designed to be subclassable. It may be used as the value of an extends clause of a class definition.` Then I'm confused. If no Object constructor is a superclass then what?

Comment: @MaximPro Property access and method invocation are features of objects, it's a general OOP pattern. Although classes of course do create objects, they're not necessary for this - in object-oriented languages that are not class-based there are many other ways to create objects.

Comment: @MaximPro Regarding inheritance, yes that's what `extends` does. Most things inherit from `Object`, `TypeError` inherits from `Error`, `Uint8Array` inherits from `TypedArray`, and so on. You can try to map out the JS builtin hierarchy as an exercise.

Comment: @MaximPro "designed to be subclassable" refers to the fact that the builtins could not be subclassed before ES6 introduced [its subclassing feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32458960/1048572). I'm not sure what you're asking by "*If no Object constructor is a superclass*".

Comment: About trying to build a hierarchy of some things. I understand how it will look and what exactly it will expand. Especially using the developer console - it will not cause difficulties.
*I'm not sure what you're asking by "If no Object constructor is a superclass"* - I meant that if the Object constructor is not a superclass, then what is the superclass in this case? I didn't really understand your link and the words: `builtins could not be subclassed before ES6 introduced its subclassing feature`

Comment: @MaximPro In which case? `Object` is a superclass of a few things, and not the superclass of other things. Regarding ES6: [It was not possible to subclass most builtins, like `Array`, before](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/).

Comment: I feel that I do not correctly understand that there is a superclass. Suppose an example: `class main {};` `class sub extends main {};` `class end extends sub {};` In this example, is `class main` a superclass for `class end`? We just create the end class using the `sub class`, but not the `class main`. And is the `class sub` a superclass for the `class end`?
Well, then if `Object` is a superclass for some things, but not for others, then I don’t understand this line for `Object` as I wrote above: `is designed to be subclassable. It can be used to extend the clauses of the class definition.`

Comment: @MaximPro `Object`, `main`, and `sub` are all superclasses of `end`, but only `sub` is the direct superclass of `end` - afaik at least. But this really depends on your exact definition of the term "superclass" and has absolutely nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: Ok, now it's clearer. But I'm still interested in: `Object is a superclass of a few things, and not the superclass of other things.` What did you mean by `...and not the superclass of other things`(for Object)? Is there a superclass for `Object`?

As for this sentence: `is designed to be subclassable. It can be used to extend the clauses of the class definition.` There was some confusion due to the fact that I did not understand the word "subclassable". As I understand it, this word in this sentence means the following meaning: `from which one can derive or inherit.` Right?

Comment: @MaximPro Yes, you understood "subclassable" right. And regarding things that `Object` is not a superclass of, you already found the first: `Object` (inheritance hierarchies are acyclic). Others are: things that are not classes, `class extends null {…}`, or classes from other realms.

Comment: I almost understood everything. Is there a superclass for `Object` class? This is the last thing I would like to know.

Comment: Is it mistake? `class extends null {…}`? You did not specify class for extending.

Comment: @MaximPro You should be able to algorithmically determine the superclass of a class now. Try to apply this algorithm to `Object` and see what the result is. Hint: When I explicitly write `null`, I mean it. You may check the spec to see how this case is handled.

Comment: What application of the `Object` algorithm are we talking about? About the hint, too, did not understand. I could check it in the specification if I understood what it was about.

Comment: I assume you are talking about this:`has a [[Prototype]] internal slot whose value is null.` in 19.1.3

Comment: @MaximPro Yes, §19.1.3. shows the superclass of `Object`.

Comment: I'm not sure what **null** is a superclass for `Object`. Since this is just a value like any other literal. Although you may have meant that there is no superclass for `Object`(Right?). I just had the ambiguity of your phrase. That is why I ask again.

Comment: Yes, `null` is not a class. As I said, the inheritance hierarchy is acyclic, so there must be something that doesn't have a superclass.

Comment: Yeah, I understand you, it was nice to talk to you again. Now my question is completely clear to me.