# Javascript class vs function when to use?

Tags: javascript

I am little bit confused when and under what circumstances we'd choose `classes` rather than `functions`.

```js
class Something {
  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

doSomthing() {
  let checkBoolen = false;
    
     document.querySelector(`.ss${this.text}`).addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
       checkBoolen = true
        console.log(this.text)
    })
    
    document.querySelector(`.ss${this.text}`).addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
      if(checkBoolen === true) {
         console.log('do something')
         checkBoolen = false
        setTimeout(function(){ console.log(checkBoolen)}, 1000)
      }
    })
  }

  newDIV() {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); 
    btn.classList.add(`ss${this.text}`)
    btn.innerHTML = `CLICK ${this.text}`;                   
    document.body.appendChild(btn);   
    this.doSomthing()
  }
}

let newdiv1 = new Something('1');
let newdiv2 = new Something('2');
newdiv1.newDIV();
newdiv2.newDIV();
```

```html
  <div id="app"></div>
```

now, if we use function

```js
function createButton(name) {

  let checkBoolen = false;
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); 
  btn.classList.add(`ss${name}`)
  btn.innerHTML = `CLICK ${name}`;                   
  document.body.appendChild(btn);   
  
   document.querySelector(`.ss${name}`).addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
        checkBoolen = true
        console.log(name)
    })
    
    document.querySelector(`.ss${name}`).addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
      if(checkBoolen === true) {
         console.log('do something')
         checkBoolen = false
        setTimeout(function(){ console.log(checkBoolen)}, 1000)
      }
    })
}

createButton('1')
createButton('2')
```

They both do the same thing, so I am a bit confused should I use `class` or `function` ? Thanks

Comment: If you use a class, make sure to transpile if you wish to support ancient obsolete browsers

Comment: At the beginning, there were no classes in JS. It is just syntactic sugar. I think it comes handful when you try to do stuff like inheritance, it could be easier for the newbies to get something working than to learn how prototypes work in JS.

Comment: To make it simple: Use a class when you need multiple copies of the same object ( instances ) that you want to add functions ( methods ) or values ( properties ) to.  The advantage is that all those objects can share the same functions but still have different values. Everything else is probably a function. The reality is way more complex than this, but that the basics.

Comment: check this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816071/prototype-based-vs-class-based-inheritance

Comment: For the record: your example is basically recreating a `<input type="checkbox">`. So in this specific case, I would use neither and prefer a real checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

> The same like in any other language - a [function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) is a way to package up some code so that it can be reused, while a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) is a “blueprint” for an [object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp), an entity that contains related code and data (methods and state).

Something a bit more specific to JavaScript are constructor functions - these are functions that act a bit like classes, in that they can be used to create new objects that will have some specific type (i.e. you can later check that an object has been created by a particular constructor function). They differ from classes in that they’re more flexible, but may sometimes require more code (specifically inheritance is a bit ugly).

Answer (score 0):

**Class Approach:**

- Class used different methods

  - If you plan to extend the functionality further.
  - If you need to manage multiple instances with individual states.
  - If you prefer an object-oriented approach or need to work in an environment where classes are commonly used.

**Function Approach:**

- Function used different methods

  - If your task is small and doesn't require much complexity.
  - If you prefer a more procedural style or if the environment doesn't support or require classes.

**Note**: Ultimately, the choice between using a class or a function depends on your specific requirements, preferences, and the overall structure of your application. Both approaches are valid, and the best choice depends on the context in which they are used.

**function reusability code and modified code with a simplified way**

```
function createButtonWithListeners(name) {
  let checkBoolean = false;

  const handleClick = () => {
    checkBoolean = true;
    console.log(name);
  };

  const handleRelease = () => {
    if (checkBoolean) {
      console.log('do something');
      checkBoolean = false;
      setTimeout(() => console.log(checkBoolean), 1000);
    }
  };

  const btn = createButton(name, handleClick, handleRelease);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}

function createButton(name, mousedownHandler, mouseupHandler) {
  const btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.classList.add(`ss${name}`);
  btn.innerHTML = `CLICK ${name}`;

  btn.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedownHandler);
  btn.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseupHandler);

  return btn;
}

createButtonWithListeners('1');
createButtonWithListeners('2');
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is about functional vs object-oriented programming and since javascript allows both, it's up to you how to handle.

You can use classes for state-full objects in your application, otherwise might use functions as long it is consistent.

More information here:

https://www.codenewbie.org/blogs/object-oriented-programming-vs-functional-programming